# Meaning of Chapter 10 Verse 94

Tags: quran, tafseer, prophet-muhammad, doubts, ahlul-kitab

I have done a lot of research on this verse, on the internet, but still haven't found a pleasurable response. The verse states: 
**"So if you are in doubt as to what We have revealed unto you, then ask those who read the book (sent) before you. The Truth hath indeed come to you from your Lord, so be not of the doubters.”**

2 question comes in my mind when looking at this verse:

1. Why exactly does Allah mention the doubt in our prophet mind?
2. What exactly does it mean when Allah says "ask those who read the book (sent) before you"...as in ask the people of the gospel or the Torah?

I hope you can clarify this verse for me so that it eliminates some doubts in my mind. If there's a better, English VERSION, of the tafsir if anyone finds can please link it in the comments below.

Jazakallahu Khair.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A translation of the verse is:

> So if you are in doubt, [O Muhammad], about that which We have revealed to you, then ask those who have been reading the Scripture before you. The truth has certainly come to you from your Lord, so never be among the doubters. (10:94)

The verse outwardly addresses the Prophet (SAW) but it implicitly addresses people in general. As Ibn Kathir says, this verse is to strengthen the faith of the Ummah by telling them that the qualities of the Prophet were in the previous revelations.

Ibn Kathir also narrates from the Prophet (SAW) that he said (in response to this verse):

> "I don't doubt, and I don't ask."

Meaning, neither does the Prophet doubt in his revelation. And nor does he ask the People of the Book because he didn't doubt in the first place. Thus, this verse is for other people through the Prophet (SAW).

The meaning of "ask those who read the book before you" is to ask the Jews who believed about the qualities of the Prophet mentioned in their scriptures. Most tafasir give the example of Abdullah ibn Salam (RA).

Other people also give the meaning that we are told to ask them about the story of Musa and Pharaoh. This is because the Surah just before had mentioned that story.

Answer (score -1):

Islam did not begin with Prophet Muhammad (SAW), rather, it is the final reinstatement of God’s universal message of mercy and guidance to humanity which has been sent down through many messengers to various peoples throughout the ages of the earth...

Proof in older scriptures ya want? I gotchu...

In Prophet Jesus’s revelations... 
•“I cannot do anything of myself. I judge as I hear and my judgement is honest because I am not seeking my own will but the will of the one who sent me” -John 5:30
•“It is written, worship the Lord, your God, and serve him only” -Luke 4:8
•“None of those who call me Lord will enter the kingdom of God, but only the one who does the will of my father in Heaven” -Matthew 7:21
•“None knows about that day or the hour, not even those angels in heaven, not the son, only the father” -Mark 13:32
•“Our father in heaven, hallowed be your name, may your will be done on earth as it is in heaven” -Matthew 6:9-10

Proof of Islam in Prophet David’s revelation...
•”I will bow down toward your holy temple and praise your name for your unfailing love and for your faithfulness. For you have so exalted your solemn decree that it surpasses your fame. When I called, you answered me. You so greatly emboldened me.” -Psalm 138:2

I mean.. I dunno how much you know and haaate typing much but if you wanna see hella more proof and a bajillion Islamic and Islamic eschatology symbolism, signs, and references, check out a viral video called “II Pet Goat 2”... So many references to hadiths, Quran verses, prophets, end of the world prophecies...

It is absolutely vital to study the Quran cover to cover literally just read as non judgementally, openmindedly, carefully and to study comparative/religion and scripture/theology/eschatology/spirituality... everything is connected... all factors mixed up... all scripture study leads to Islam, a single reality/truth, oneness/tawheed, if you were to believe..

Things are not how they appear. The truth is between the lines, the vibe, the overall message, the allegory. Scripture is universally symbolic and is a total mirror...